# pip doesn't perform to install a module in Python 2.7, Windows 7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pip, easy-install

For Windows 7, x64, I'm trying to configure some libraries in Python. I use Python 2.7.11 and the Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7. When I try to install the library 'numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl' using pip or easy_install, like:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts pip install D:\Downloads\numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Nothing happens! I only see blank and can't do anything against it. After searching many pages about similar issues, I followed the instructions from this page:

http://arunrocks.com/guide-to-install-python-or-pip-on-windows/

Thus after installing pip and easy_install in the same path as Python and checking my environment variable the problem still persists..
Do anybody know what else I can do to use pip, or to install the wanted libraries? I'm really thankful for any idea!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the --use-wheel flag, and also have installed wheel.  For example:

```
pip install wheel
pip install --use-wheel yourfile.whl
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast Response! But that doesn't work for me either! I don't understand why pip doesn't operate for my system. Besides I've installed wheel.exe with Python.

Comment: Does pip work for other libraries?  Also, pip should come already installed with Python 2.7.11, see this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows  So I wonder if perhaps when you installed pip again, it was an incompatible version?  You might try reinstalling Python and try pip out the of box.  You'll need to add both C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts to your system PATH variable.

Comment: No, pip works for no other library also. I see that pip is in the Folder C:\Python27\Scripts\ . I installed a second time Python2.7 and one time Python 3.4.4. But both times pip doesn't work for any reason. I also added the two directories to my system PATH. What else can I try?

Comment: `C:\envs>python get-pip.py` `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages`

Comment: Is it possible there might be another python installation somewhere?  If so, it could be a path resolution order issue.  I recently had an issue, with a copy of python that was installed with MySQL Workbench, that was mucking things up.  If you are sure there are no other python.exe files on your path, I would suggest perhaps reinstalling Python from scratch.  Then try the two lines that I posted again.  Pip should definitely be installed with Python, you should not have to install it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows Account doesnt have full persmissions. Maybe it says its Administrator, but something (ex Server) blocks some operations. I had the same issue at work, I couldnt install PIP but also XAMPP server on my PC.
However, I solved 1st issue - simply ran CMD as Admin, then went to 
C:\Python27 and typed:

```
python.exe -m pip install MySQLdb
```

so PIP worked, and finally I updated it:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

P.S: I had 2 pythons 2.7 and 3.5 but did not reinstall or delete anything.